# Javascript unit tests for Web Api REST services?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I have a Web API controller action that takes a quite complex object as an argument. It's to be passed to the webservice as JSON, of course, and is supposed to deserialize into an instance of a C# class.

I have unit tests in the business layer to convince me that JSON serialization/deserialization of the class in question works as expected.

And I have C# unit tests running against the Web API controllers, passing instances of this class into the actions, to ensure that if the controller actions have the right behavior, given the correct objects.

My problem: these objects are complicated enough that constructing improper JSON isn't going to be easy. My intent is to create some convenience functions, in Javascript, to aid in that construction, and I'd like to have unit tests to make sure that they work, and unit tests to ensure that properly-formatted JSON is deserialized into the target class as expected.

That means I need to create, in my VS2013 solution, a way to run javascript, both as self-contained unit tests, and as calls against my Web API webservice.

Any suggestions as to what tooling would work best for that?

I'd really like something that can be contained within Visual Studio, so that it can be configured as an MsBuild target.  (Would make the guys who deal with the Continuous Integration configuration much happier.)

Comment: Can you add the signature for the method(s) that you are trying to test to the question?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant.